# Shorten way to write code and respect DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I wonder if this code

```
-matches.each do |match|
    =match.clan_1.name
    =match.score(clan_1)
    =match.clan_2.name
    =match.score(clan_2)
```

can become something like this:

```
-matches.each do
    =clan_1.name
    =score(clan_1)
    =clan_2.name
    =score(clan_2)
```

I think it will be much more DRY.
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you intend your code to do? Your code examples aren't very clear.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of repeating match near every element.

Comment: But you're iterating over each match in matches right? If you remove match then you don't have an object to work with.

Comment: Yeah, and that's why I want to move whole match into main namespace.

Comment: Aah, I see what you're trying to do. I'm not sure there's a way to do this in Ruby. Short of writing a custom iterator I'd probably settle for shortening match to m so you only have to write m. every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
-matches.each do |match|
    -match.instance_eval do
        =clan_1.name
        =score(clan_1)
        =clan_2.name
        =score(clan_2)
```

Comment: In my opinion you've just made your code dirty by doing this.

Comment: This is becoming more and more popular, especially in rails 3. Most config blocks are now in this format

Answer (score 0):

The best way to DRY this up would be to stick it in a helper method and call that from your views.